How to use specific elements from the Lepton-x Theme, e.g., private chat page?
I'm trying to use specific elements from the Lepton-x theme (example: the private chat page: Private Chat Example) in my own project.
https://x.leptontheme.com/side-menu/custom-pages/private-chat
I inspected the HTML using browser developer tools and tried copying the structure and styles, but some parts don't work as expected (e.g., missing JavaScript functionalities or CSS styles).
Is there a better way to integrate these elements into my project? Should I copy the entire structure (HTML, CSS, JS) or is there a more efficient approach to reuse components from the theme?
Any advice or examples would be appreciated.

Are there specific modules I can use (ABP provides) for the specific UI elements?

mmh, what could be the solution
